# Pygame def functions

Tags: python, pygame, function

I defined some functions in pygame.

```
import time
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*
def screen(a,b,z,v):
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((a,b),z,v)
def image1(a,x,y):
    b = pygame.image.load(a).convert()
    screen.blit(b,(x,y))
```

And I added some code:

```
a = "white.jpg"
screen(50,50,0,32)
```

However, I did not get a window as usual. Why is this so? To make the question clearer, this is what i get:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>>
```

And it get stuck there and not loading and sometimes the python prompt closes itself. Can someone explain?
*edit:
i defined other functions in the codes. It appears that there are too many functions defined. How do i stop the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be other bits missing,but you need to call `pygame.init()` before you do anything else.

You could add that call in your `screen function`, or before calling it in your main code:

```
def screen(a,b,z,v):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((a,b),z,v)
```

or

```
pygame.init()
screen(50,50,0,32)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better late then never, I had the same problem at first because I forgot to add this,

```
for event in pygame.event.get():              
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
        pygame.quit()
```